# DAX group by one column and keep corresponding value from another

Tags: powerbi, dax

Quick question, I'm sure this is simpler than i'm making it out to be.

So lets say I have a table with 3 columns

```
colA   colB   colC
D      Adam   100
D      Dennis 200
D      Tim    300
C      Sharon 450
C      Cindy  400
```

How do I group by colA,take the max of colC and return the corresponding value for colB

e.g.

```
colA   colB    colC
D      Tim     300
C      Sharon  450
```

I hope that makes sense. Cheers guys!

Comment: Do you want this as a new calculated table or as a matrix/table visual?

Comment: Either would do, it's purely for the visualisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to add a rank column to your table and then do a visual level Top N filter.

```
Rank = RANKX(
           FILTER(
               ALL( Table1 ),
               Table1[colA] = EARLIER( Table1[colA] )
           ),
           Table1[colC]
       )
```

Once you have that new column, add `colA`, `colB`, and `colC` to a table or matrix visual and put the `Rank` column into the visual level filters section and choose

```
Filter Type: Top N
Show items: Bottom 1
By value: Rank
```

Then your table should only display the maximal `colC` value per `colA` value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the below. However, this will likely give an error if [colC] contains duplicate values for a specific [colA] value.

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    'MyTable'[colA],
    "colB", 
        VAR maxC = MAX('MyTable'[colC])
        RETURN CALCULATE(VALUES('MyTable'[colB]), 'MyTable'[colC] = maxC)
    "colC",
        MAX('MyTable'[colC])
)
```